# After a table view cell is clicked, in the next controller it is removed from the list of item

Tags: xcode, arrays, uitableview

I do not really have much idea how to get this done but the idea is that in the first view controller, it will have an array of 6 items. After any of the table view cell is clicked, that particular cell will be removed and the next controller will display the remaining 5 items.

in the FirstController .m

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    SecondController *sc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondController"];
    filteredFive = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    // I only display two of it here as it will be very lengthy
    if ([[totalItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"ONE"]) {
        [filteredFive addObject:@"TWO"];
        [filteredFive addObject:@"THREE"];
        [filteredFive addObject:@"FOUR"];
        [filteredFive addObject:@"FIVE"];
        [filteredFive addObject:@"SIX"];
    }

    if ([[totalItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"TWO"]) {
        [filteredFive addObject:@"ONE"];
        [filteredFive addObject:@"THREE"];
        [filteredFive addObject:@"FOUR"];
        [filteredFive addObject:@"FIVE"];
        [filteredFive addObject:@"SIX"];
    }
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:sc animated:NO];
    // this is the part I am trying to transfer the array filteredFive into SecondController's array
    sc.fiveItems = filteredFive;
```

Then at SecondController.h

```
@interface SecondController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {
    NSMutableArray *fiveItems;
}
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *secondTable;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *fiveItems;

@end
```

SecondController.m

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [fiveItems count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.textLabel.text = [fiveCourses objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    return cell;
}
```

I am wondering if there is any errors in my codes that I have that disallow the data to be shown. Is it that I failed to transfer the array from one to another? Or am I missing some code thus the code is not showing in the SecondController?

If there is another way to display the 5 remaining items, I will be willing to try too.

Comment: This might or might not be the problem, depending on how the property was synthesized, but I suggest removing `{NSMutableArray *fiveItems;}` from the header file and reference the property instead of the variable.  (e.g. `cell.textLabel.text = [self.fiveItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`)

Comment: I tried removing the NSMutableArray and reference the property but it is still not showing.

Comment: Do you have the data source set up right for the second controller?  If so, what does it return for `numberOfRowsInSection:`?

Comment: What datasource do you mean? For numberOfRowsInSections:, it is return [fiveItems count];

Comment: I mean the one for that controller's table.  So, if you log the value of `[fiveItems count]` in `numberOfRowsInSections:`, what does it say?

Comment: It is correct if I put NSLog(@"%u",[fiveCourses count]); right? but nothing is showing

Comment: I just edited the SecondController.m

Comment: If `numberOfRowsInSections:` is not being called, then I'd go back to speculating that your `SecondController` isn't set as a data source for its table.

Comment: I tried inserting the array in the viewDidLoad instead of getting it from the FirstController and the values showed up. So I am wondering if that the array data has failed to be transferred